# backgroundImage Not working in my file.js

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I'm trying to use element.backgroundImage on JS but never change the background.

I changed the file scss to test if it worked and it did but then it was fixed and seems like file js not working :(

Is not a problem with the link on the html or something like that 'cause everything else is working...

Here's the sass:

```scss
.body-movie {
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: fit-content;
  position: relative;
  /* background-image = url('../scss/img/image-1.jpg') */
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Here the js:

```js
const movieSelect = {
  name: 'Saw',
  back: '../scss/img/image-2.jpg'
}
const back = document.querySelector('.body-movie');
back.style.backgroundImage = `${movieSelect.back}`;
```

I want the `image-2.jpg` in the background but `image-1.jpg` still there even though it is commented.

Comment: Why is your JS referencing SASS resources?

Comment: `movieSelect` is invalid. You want an object, not an array.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: @Andy Yeah, was a mistake of copy/paste but in the file is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If image-1 is still there even though its commented out, then that means you need to refresh or page or recompile your sass in some way.

For the JS, it's not working because you are neglecting to include the "url(" portion of the string.  So you would need

```
back.style.backgroundImage = `url(${movieSelect.back})`;
```

Comment: Thankss!! Was missing 'url()'

Comment: That won't work. You're setting the background image url to `${movieSelect.back}` If there is going to be a string literal, you need to do use the back ticks around the whole string  ``  `url(${movieSelect.back})`  `` (no quotes)